# jQuery losing selecting when dialog box is opened

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var $dialog = $("#dialog-box").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                position: "center",
                draggable: true,
            });

            var $optionsdialog = $("#optionsdialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                position: "center",
                draggable: true,
            });

            $(function () {
                $("#column1, #column2, #column3").sortable({
                    connectWith: $(".column"),
                    placeholder: 'widget-placeholder',
                    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
                    revert: 300,
                    delay: 100,
                    opacity: 0.8,
                    containment: 'document',
                    cancel: '.header',
                    stop: function (event, ui) {
                        $optionsdialog.dialog("open")
                    },
                })
            });

            $(".widget-content").bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                $("#dropmenu").css({
                    top: e.pageY + 'px',
                    left: e.pageX + 'px'
                }).show();
                return false;
            });

            $(".widget-content").hover(function () {
                $(this).addClass("selected");
            });

            $(".optitemlist").click(function () {
                $(".widget-content").empty();
                $(".widget-content").append('<img class="listimg" src="img/list.png" alt="#" />');
                $optionsdialog.dialog("close");
            });

            $(".optitemwimage").click(function () {
                $(".widget-content").empty();
                $(".widget-content").append('<img class="listimg" src="img/listimage.png" alt="#" />');
                $optionsdialog.dialog("close");
            });

            $(".itemlist").click(function () {
                var $selectedContent = $(".selected");
                $selectedContent.empty();
                $selectedContent.append('<img class="listimg" src="img/list.png" alt="#" />');
                var selected = $("#columns").find("div").hasClass(".selected");
                $(selected).removeClass("selected");
            });

            $(".itemwimage").click(function () {
                $(".widget-content").empty();
                $(".widget-content").append('<img class="listimg" src="img/listimage.png" alt="#" />');
            });

            $(".editproperties").click(function () {
                $dialog.dialog("open");
            });

            $('#dropmenu').click(function () {
                $('#dropmenu').hide();
            });

            $(document).click(function () {
                $('#dropmenu').hide();
            });

            $(".remove").click(function () {
                $(this).parents(".sort").clone().appendTo("#column1");
                $(this).parents(".sort").animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, function () {
                    $(this).wrap('<div/>').parent().slideUp(function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                });
            });

            $("#saveButton").click(function () {
                if ($("#checkBox").is(":checked")) {
                    $(".sort h3").show();
                }
                else {
                    $(".sort h3").hide();
                }
            });


        });

    </script>
```

```
<div id="columns">


    <ul id="column1" class="column">
        <li class="widget header" id="column1title">
            <div class="widget-title">
                <h3>Channels:</h3>
            </div>               
        </li>

        <li class="widget sort">  
            <div class="widget-head">
                <h3 class="title">Widget title 1</h3>
                <a href="#" class="remove">[ x ]</a>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-content">
                <img class="listimg" src="img/list.png" alt="#" />
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="widget sort">  
            <div class="widget-head">
                <h3 class="title">Widget title 2</h3>
                <a href="#" class="remove">[ x ]</a>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-content">
                <img class="listimg" src="img/list.png" alt="#" />
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="widget sort">  
            <div class="widget-head">
                <h3 class="title">Widget title 3</h3>
                <a href="#" class="remove">[ x ]</a>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-content">
                <img class="listimg" src="img/list.png" alt="#" />
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>

    <ul id="column2" class="column">
        <li class="widget header" id="column2title">  
            <div class="widget-title">
                <h3>ROW 0 COLUMN 0</h3>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="column3" class="column">
        <li class="widget header" id="column3title">  
            <div class="widget-title">
                <h3>ROW 0 COLUMN 1</h3>
            </div>
        </li>   
    </ul>

    <ul id="dropmenu" class="contextMenu">    
        <li class="itemlist">
            <a href="#">Item List</a>

        </li>            
        <li class="itemwimage">
            <a href="#">Featured Item w/ full image</a>
        </li>      

        <li class="editproperties">
            <a href="#">Edit Properties</a>
        </li>                    
    </ul>

    <ul id="optionsdialog">    
        <li class="optitemlist">
            <a href="#">Item List</a>

        </li>            
        <li class="optitemwimage">
            <a href="#">Featured Item w/ full image</a>
        </li>                         
    </ul>



<div id="dialog-box" class="dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable ">
   <div class="ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
       <span id="ui-dialog-title-dialog" class="ui-dialog-title">Edit Properties</span>
       <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#"></a>
       </div>
        <div style="height: auto; min-height: 300px; width: auto;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="dialog">
                <p>Change the title?</p>  <input id="title" value=" "/><br /><br />
                <p> Show title?</p>  <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox" /><br /><br />
                <p> # of Items To Display?</p>  <select name="choice" size="1"><option value="">1</option><option value="">2</option><option value="">3</option><option value="">4</option><option value="">5</option><option value="">6</option><option value="">7</option><option value="">8</option><option value="">9</option><option value="">10</option></select><br /><br />
                <p> More Link Title</p><input value="More Usability Items"/><br /><br />
                <p> More Link Url</p><input value="/tag/usability.aspx"/><br /><br />
                <p> CSS Class</p><input value="WebUsabiltiyCssClass"/><br /><br />
                <input id="saveButton" class="ui-button" type="button" value="Save" />
        </div> 
</div>  

<div id="saveDiv">
<br /><br /><input type="button" class="savebutton" value="Save Template and Close" />  <input type="button" class="savebutton" value="Save Template and Continue" />&nbsp;&nbsp; or <a href="#" class="cancel">Cancel</a>
</div>

    </div>
```

This is my first jQuery project and the issue I'm having is whenever I open the dialog box or right click, it's obviously lost the selection for the widget.

For example, when I move one of the .sort widgets it prompts whether I want an itemlist or an itemlistwimage. Instead of just changing the option for one widget, it's changing all of them. How do I select just one since I'm no longer focused on that element?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey there! Why don't you upload your project to jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) so we can test it real time and debug it?

Comment: It's nice that you provided the code, but it'd be even nicer if you could isolate the problem and post a minimized code example with the steps to reproduce the issue. Meanwhile, here's a jsfiddle with your code and jQuery UI included: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/umxzw/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to pass along the relevant information: http://jsfiddle.net/umxzw/1/

I added

```
$optionsdialog.data('content', $(ui.item).find('.widget-content'));
```

to the sortable.stop function and modified the click handlers of ".optitemlist" and ".optitemwimage" to use that data.